# How to compile Python 3 programs using Sublime Text

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm trying to set up Sublime Text 3 for Python to do a college project, but for some reason I can't compile or build programs in it. I get the following error:

```
Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store
```

What's the fix?

Comment: Have you installed Python3 in Windows? If not, then download and install python via this link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/python-3.8.1-amd64.exe

Comment: Yes i did install Python3, CMD works with it.

Comment: Ok, can you verify if you type `python` in CMD, it opens Python command prompt?

Comment: I think this might be helpful. Just replace `python3` with `python`; https://gist.github.com/zaemiel/4fbd8b5125fda7a140be

Comment: If I type python in CMD it opens up the Windows Store's link for downloading Python

Comment: Hey I tried the github solution but it did not work, still pops up the same error